# The 2 parameter of the RemoveChars function, which is now 0, must be a positive integer

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting this error when browsing to the zzvp.cfm page

```
The 2 parameter of the RemoveChars function, which is now 0, must be a positive integer


The error occurred in /www/zzvp.cfm: line 578
 Called from /www/zzvp.cfm: line 530
 Called from /www/zzvp.cfm: line 1
 576 :              <cfset updir = #RemoveChars(updir, len(updir), 1)#>
 577 :              <cfloop condition = "Right(updir, 1) neq '\'">
 578 :                  <cfset updir = #RemoveChars(updir, len(updir), 1)#>
 579 :              </cfloop>
 580 :              <th class=chkbx><input type=checkbox width='13px'
   class=chkbx></th><td width="20%"><strong><a href="?action=goto&scr=#updir#">..</a></strong></td>`
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says. You are calling the [RemoveChars](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3e.html) function with a bad parameter.  As mentioned in the documentation - and error message, the second parameter must be greater than zero.  What have you tried so far to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not getting the logic behind the code, the following describes your issue.

Error is coming because the string length become zero, and still `\` was not found. Add an extra condition to check the length of the string in loop.

```
<cfloop condition = "Right(updir, 1) neq '\' AND  len(updir)">
    <cfset updir = RemoveChars(updir, len(updir), 1)>
</cfloop>
```

For this logic I think there are better ways to implement this logic without loops. See the following.

```
<!--- Treat string as a list with \ as delimiter ---> 
<cfset updir = ListDeleteAt(updir, listlen(updir,'\'), '\') >
```

or

```
<!--- Reverse string --->
<cfset updir = Reverse(updir)> 
<!--- Get from left till the position of the \  --->
<cfset updir = Left( Reverse(updir), len(updir) - find(updir , '\') + 1 ) >
```

Comment: after making the first set of changes

`<cfloop condition = "Right(updir, 1) neq '\' AND  len(updir)">
    <cfset updir = RemoveChars(updir, len(updir), 1)>
</cfloop>
<!--- Treat string as a list with \ as delimiter ---> 
<cfset updir = ListDeleteAt(updir, listlen(updir,'\'), '\') >`

i get the same  error but on line 577

575 :   <cfif len(dir) gt 3>
576 :    <tr>
577 :     <cfset updir = #dir#>
578 : <cfset updir = #RemoveChars(updir, len(updir), 1)#>
579 : <cfloop condition = "Right(updir, 1) neq '\' AND  len(updir)">

Comment: @martin No need for looping. Replace the `cfloop` with this `<cfset list = ListDeleteAt(list, listlen(list,'\'), '\') >`. I'll try to figure out the reason for error. Can you post a sample input?

Comment: so removing the loop and ending up looking like this

<cfset updir = #dir#>
  <cfset updir = #RemoveChars(updir, len(updir), 1)#>
    
 <cfset updir = ListDeleteAt(updir, listlen(updir,'\'), '\') >

Comment: @martin What I am saying is to replace the whole `<cfloop>` block.

`<cfset updir = dir>`
`<cfset updir = ListDeleteAt(updir, listlen(updir,'\'), '\') >`

Comment: hi, thanks but i am failing to make it work even with your changes. but thanks for you assistance anyways